# GoogleApiClient.connect() never calls onConnected

Tags: java, android

So I have a problem where I instantiate the Google API Client as shown below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_nearby_locs);
    buildGoogleApiClient();

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

And in my onStart() and onResume() I call connect

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

By adding a breakpoint to the onConnected() method I can see it never calls it, and hence my lat long values are never set as onConnected() calls my setters.

Anyone else have a similar problem? If so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: maybe it calls `onConnectionFailed` ... fx if google api is not supported on this device

Comment: Which package you imported? and may be onConnctionFailed called.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that onConnectionFailed() also never gets called I have a breakpoint in there also.

Comment: Check the logs, I'm sure Google placed some usefull logs to help debug